# Is it better to have more links to the homepage on your website?

Tags: html, hyperlinks, homepage

Is it a good idea to have more than 2 or 3 links to the homepage on your website?

Think about something like:

- Link in Footer
- Link in Header (obvious)
- Link in content
- Link the headerlogo to homepage

Is it easier? or just too generous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a good idea, since this is almost convention today. If you take a look at any web site* today almost all text (and images) in footer, header and header logo are hypertext links.

When you implement links try to differentiate between header/footer links which should be displayed as static and not show recently visited in another color such as inline links. Inline links should display with visited or not visited differently so that the user knows whether or not she have visited the link or not.

---

<sup>*)Social media web sites such as Facebook, Twitter and Google Plus. Newspapers such as The New York Times and Dagens Nyheter (Swedish) or shopping sites such as Amazon or e-bay.</sup>